# Model flips around origin point when applying a Mirrored Shape Key

Tags: shape-keys, object-mode

I'm currently trying to create *Shape Keys* for facial expressions on my character. When I got to the point of trying to mirror them, I was able to successfully mirror them with Shape Mirror (Topology). But when I do, the model seems to sort of turn inside out around the origin point.

This happens consistently with 2 of the objects I was using shape keys for (body and eyelids), but not a third object which was made recently (eyebrows).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it !

[image]

In case anyone else had the same problem, some of my object properties were a little off. Despite being upward, it was seen as being rotated -360 degrees.

I went to *Object > Apply > All Transformations* and that seemed to fix it !